# Django - Wrong datetime on server

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I've deployed my Django application on DigitalOcean server. Everything works fine, except date. So, hours are displaying different (inside the document time is displaying 4 hour late) on admin dashboard and inside the model instance. During export to excel time also wrong.

P.S: I'm using `flatpickr` for `DateTimeField`:

```
var d = new Date($.now());
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            flatpickr(".datetimefield", {
                enableTime: true,
                enableSeconds: true,
                dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i:S",
                time_24hr: true,
                locale: "az",
                defaultDate: `${d.getFullYear()}-${d.getMonth()+1}-${d.getDate()} ${d.getHours()}:${d.getMinutes()}:00`
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your time zone is US/Eastern. Try changing these settings in `settings.py`:

`TIME_ZONE = 'US/Eastern'` and
`USE_TZ = False`

Setting `USE_TZ` to `False` lets you use your preferred time zone for your server.

Comment: Setting `USE_TZ` to `False` helped me.